# ¿Como puedo pasar un vector de objetos como parametro hacia un constructor?

Tags: java, java-swing, java-8, controller, parametros

Tengo esto declarado en un controlador llamado CPrincipal, pero me da error, no se como es la sintaxis.

```
Ccliente cc = new Ccliente(mc, vc);
```

El Controlador que va a recibir tiene:

```
Cliente c[] = {new Cliente(null, null, 0, null, null, null, null, 0, 0, null)};
Vcliente vc = new Vcliente();


public Ccliente(Cliente[] c, Vcliente vc) {
    super();
    this.c = c;
    this.vc = vc;
    this.vc.addRegistroListener(new registrarValor());
    this.vc.addBuscarListener(new buscarValor());
    vc.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Cuál es el error?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Por favor, cuando decis que hay un error, Aclaranos cual es el error!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

algo que se ve así a simple vista:

```
Cliente c = new Cliente(null, null, 0, null, null, null, null, 0, 0, null);// si solo te interesa pasar uno no necesariamente ties que declararlo como array
Cliente c[] = {{new Cliente(null, null, 0, null, null, null, null, 0, 0, null)}, new Cliente(null, null, 0, null, null, null, null, 0, 0, null)};//esto sería un array.
Vcliente vc = new Vcliente();


public Ccliente(Cliente c, Vcliente vc) {
    super();
    this.c = c;
    this.vc = vc;
    this.vc.addRegistroListener(new registrarValor());
    this.vc.addBuscarListener(new buscarValor());
    vc.setVisible(true);
}
```

El error supongo que viene cuando intentas hacer las asignaciones "this.c = c;"
al ser declarado como array en el paramtro el espera que ese objeto sea recorrido con un for o foreach y dentro del for poder hacer las asignaciones correspondientes, tal y como ahora lo tienes estás asignando no un objeto sino una referencia a la memoria donde se encuentra ese objeto.

Yo probaría asi. y si no, nos lo comentas y miro otra solución. Saludos.

Comment: Probé exactamente el código así (variando la primera línea) y no me funcionó. Si dejo la declaracion de primera linea me da error en el this.c y en todo donde lo uso. De la segunda forma me da error solo en él y en el otro controlador que envia los parametros.

Comment: @AlexYánez Prueba algo así:                                                                                                         ```public Ccliente(Cliente[] c, Vcliente vc) {
            foreach( Cliente cliente: c){
                super();
                this.c = cliente;
            }
             this.vc = vc;
                this.vc.addRegistroListener(new registrarValor());
                this.vc.addBuscarListener(new buscarValor());
                vc.setVisible(true);
            }
        }                
       ```